# Handling nulls on freetext

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, freetext

I am trying to use `FREETEXT`. The @name field often has nulls and this is not an error in the program. It just means that other search approaches are being used.

Originally I had

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(50) = ... -- some value which many be NULL or blank

SELECT ID 
FROM dbo.Data WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE  FREETEXT(*, @Name)
```

I tried

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(50) = ... -- some value which many be NULL or blank

SELECT ID 
FROM dbo.Data WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE @Name IS NOT NULL AND  FREETEXT(*, @Name)
```

But I still get

> Msg 7645, Level 15, State 2, Line 3 Null or empty full-text predicate.

What is a good approach to get around this?

**additional note**

```
SELECT ID 
FROM dbo.data WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE FREETEXT(*, ' ')
```

also throws and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

try this:

```
SET @Name = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Name, ''), '<null>');

SELECT ID
FROM dbo.Data
WHERE FREETEXT(*, @Name)
```

**older answer:**

One option is to use nullif to convert empty strings to null, followed by isnull to convert nulls to a string with a single space.

```
SELECT ID
FROM dbo.Data
WHERE FREETEXT(*, isnull(nullif(@Name, ''), ' '))
```

Comment: I am getting: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'isnull'.`

Answer (score 1):

Updated statement from Zohar seems to be working..I just added a declare statement below:

declare @Name varchar(20) = ''
  set @Name = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Name, ''), '');
  select Author_id from Author
  where freetext(*,@Name)